# Preventing Apache to access root FS via exec

Tags: apache-http-server, exec

Actually I discovered that I can access the root via exec in php 
something like

```
<?php
   echo exec('cat /etc/passwd');
?>
```

will print the content of the passwd file, note that with `cd` command I can easly navigate where ever I want, so how can I correct this ? Defining a kind of virtual root for example limited to the actuel directory

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The file `cat /etc/passwd` is read-only by default to all users. The file doesn't contain critical information. It's normal behaviour for a user (be it www-data/apache or anyone else) to be able to browse the filesystem. However some files are restricted for all users except the super user (root). If any process under Apache can access for example `/etc/shadow` you have a serious permission problem, as the file contains the encrypted passwords of all users.

Now if you don't want PHP to be able to access the filesystem there are number of ways to counteract this behaviour. **Also note that this behaviour is not a security risk by itself, as the file permissions control who and what can modify or view files/directories.**

1. Before PHP *5.4.0* there was something called safe-mode that could be used to limit the users access. (it had a number of issues and therefore later removed).
2. You can disallow all the shell commands (system, exec, passthru).
3. Use [open_basedir](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)